# How does Rocket performance compare to other things?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, performance

Typically cars are rated on their 0-60 mph times. (Tesla's currently kicking some serious gas car butt, where the P90D with Ludicrous mode hitting 2.8s which is literally ludicrous. As in you can hurt yourself just hitting the gas pedal).

For a faster vehicle, I am thinking 0-Mach 1 is more fun time to consider.

Looking at the [Thaicomm-8 mission timeline at Spaceflightnow.com](https://spaceflightnow.com/2016/05/25/timeline-for-falcon-9s-launch-of-thaicom-8/) it suggests from a standing start, to Mach 1 at 1 minute 10 seconds.

That is pretty darn good. 70 seconds to Mach 1.

How does that time compare for:
a) Other boosters.
b) Fighter jets
c) What else can exceed Mach 1 under power?

Man, the drag racing videos of a Tesla Model S against various gas powered 'super cars' are fun to watch.  Can you imagine a Falcon 9 vs F-22 race? That would be cool. Impossible, but cool!

Comment: Fastest accelerating electric motorcycle does 0-60 in under 1 second :-)

Comment: Don't forget that Mach 1 is a relative speed.

Comment: @RoryAlsop That sounds painful. How many G's does it take to get 0-60mph in under 1 second?  60 mph=100kph=27.8 m/s  And Accel=Velocity/time.  So 27.8 m/s divided by 1 second, so 9.8 m/s/s is 1 G so almost 3 G's of accel?  That is lower than I expected.

Comment: It is purely because it is electric - max torque the whole way up as opposed to gear changes

Comment: And Mach 1 is just the start for a booster.

Comment: The important factor for rockets is not acceleration, but delta-v, hence thus comparisons are quite meaningless. You can easily design rockets that have accelerations that kill humans. Important things are Isp of engines, Payload to LEO / GEO and delta-v given a nominal payload.

Comment: "That is pretty darn good. 70 seconds to Mach 1." Bear in mind most of that is an initial climb too. How many other things accelerate almost **vertically** while flying at Mach 1? I don't think there's much comparison really, especially considering the huge fuel consumption rates of rockets.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure you'll get much useful data, but here's a useful datum point:

[Bloodhound SSC](http://www.bloodhoundssc.com/) - the worlds fastest car is expected to reach 1000mph in 55 seconds from rest (42 seconds would be a perfect run, but 55 is the expected run), with a peak acceleration of 2g.

0 - 300mph (Point a) using the EJ-200 jet engine (generating around 0.5g), where the rocket will be ignited (total acceleration from the two hitting 2g) until maximum speed of around 1050mph, where the rocket will be cut off (Point b)

Interestingly deceleration will be around 3g from aerodynamic drag alone! Brakes will be used at Point c - for about 0.25g deceleration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fastest road cars in the world accelerate at around 1 G, and acceleration drops off rapidly as speed increases. Rockets reach accelerations of 3-5 G just before burnout of the first stage.